# Laravel - activation link in email doesn't appear as link

Tags: php, laravel

I have registration form with activation. So the user register his accoount then he receive email with link to activate his account. The problem is that the link is appear in the email like text not like URL. What can be the problem? Here is **activate.blade.php**

```
Hello {{ $username }}<br><br>
Please activate your account using the following link<br><br>
---<br>
{{ $link }} <br>
---
```

And here is the **AccountController** mail send

```
Mail::send('emails.auth.activate', array(
                  'link' => URL::route('account-activate', $code), 
                  'username' => $username), 
                  function($message) use ($user) {
   $message->to($user->email, $user->username)->subject('Activate your account');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to create an html link, if you want it to be clickable:

```
Hello {{ $username }}<br><br>
Please activate your account using the following link<br><br>
---<br>
<a href="{{$link}}">{{$link}}</a><br>
```

Although some email clients already do that automatically, I think.

`URL::route('account-activate', $code)` creates only the url, not the link.

Comment: Yes, that way is working. Also I just tried in another email (Gmail) and there is appearing like link.. I guess they do it automatically. Thank's for help!

Comment: where do you put this html link in your view? to see the link in the message in your email?